# Why is this code showing test case error?

Tags: java

**QUESTION**
Monocarp wrote down two numbers on a whiteboard. Both numbers follow a specific format: a positive integer ***x*** with ***p*** zeros appended to its end.

Now Monocarp asks you to compare these two numbers. Can you help him?

**Input**
The first line contains a single integer ***t*** **(1 ≤** ***t*** **≤ 10<sup>4</sup>)** — the number of test cases.

The first line of each test case contains two integers ***x1*** and ***p1*** **(1 ≤** ***x1*** **≤ 10<sup>6</sup>;0 ≤** ***p1*** **≤ 10<sup>6</sup>)** — the description of the first number.

The second line of each test case contains two integers ***x2*** and ***p2*** **(1 ≤** ***x2*** **≤ 10<sup>6</sup>;0 ≤** ***p2*** **≤ 10<sup>6</sup>)** — the description of the second number.

**Output**
For each testcase print the result of the comparison of the given two numbers. If the first number is smaller than the second one, print `<`. If the first number is greater than the second one, print `>`. If they are equal, print `=`.

**MY CODE**

```java
import java.util.*;
public class A_1613_LongComparison_Contest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int i=0, ans1=0, ans2=0, j=0, pow=0;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<3;j++)
            {
                System.out.print("");
                int x=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("");
                int p=sc.nextInt();
                if(j==1)
                {
                    pow=(int)(Math.pow(10,p));
                    ans1=x*pow;
                }
                else
                {
                    pow=(int)(Math.pow(10,p));
                    ans2=x*pow;
                }
            }
            if(ans1>ans2)
                System.out.println(">");
            else if(ans1==ans2)
                System.out.println("=");
            else
                System.out.println("<");
        }
    }
}
```

This problem is taken from codeforces contest. This is my first question so sorry for pasting it all
**Link of problem** https://codeforces.com/contest/1613/problem/A
**It is showing wrong on a test case i cant see, please help me find problem**
**thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### int overflow

Example input:

```
1
1 12
1000000 6
```

Expected output:

```
=
```

Actual output from your program:

```
>
```

**Why was that?**

For the first number, `Math.pow(10, 12)` correctly yields 1 000 000 000 000.0 as a Java `double`. This is too big for an `int`, so when you cast it, it is cast to 2 147 483 647, the greatest possible `int` value. So `ans1` becomes 2 147 483 647. One would have expected an error to be reported, but that does not happen.

For the second number, not only does `pow()` correctly return 1 000 000.0, the number is also converted to an `int` with the same value, 1 000 000. But then the multiplcation causes overflow, and instead of 1 000 000 000 000 you get: -727 379 968. That’s right, a negative number.

So are those number equal? Not at all. `ans1` is greater. Therefore `>` is printed.

### Any solution?

The immediate solution is to use `BigInteger` for your math instead of `int`. Whether you are under performance restrictions that cause this not to work for your challenge, I don’t know. If so, you will have to think out a still cleverer solution. It’s meant to be part of the challenge, so I am not taking it away from you. I can think of at least one smart option (teasing, I know).

The range of `long` isn’t large enough either. They go up to 9.22 * 10<sup>18</sup>. You would need 1 * 10<sup>1000006</sup>. So the next natural step would be to learn to use `BigInteger`. The syntax is quite different, but the mathematical concepts should still be familiar.